# How to store elapsed time of a variable assignment to another variable in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I wanted to run a maven command and store the console output to a variable and in turn, store the `real` time of the mentioned operation in another variable. I wrote the following command -

```
x1=`( time t1=$( mvn test -Drat.skip)) 2>&1 | grep real`
```

When I `echo` variable `x1` I get `0m17.430s` which is the desired output but when I `echo` variable `t1` it prints nothing! How can I store the console output of `mvn test -Drat.skip` in `t1`?

Comment: If you like to measure the time I would also give `mvn -q ..` to suppress any output on console cause you are only interested in output of `time`...

Comment: Actually I want to capture all the `[INFO]` and `[DEBUG]` logs.

Comment: `[DEBUG] ` will only appear if you use `mvn -X ...`...furthermore for time measuring it will not help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything inside of `()` or backticks happens in a subshell. Variable values aren't exported from a subshell back to the parent shell.

You can assign both the output of the command and output of `time` into a variable and then extract it from there:

```
#!/bin/bash
all=$((time mvn test -Drat.skip )2>&1)
time=$(tail -n3 <<< "$all" | grep real)
output=$(head -n-3 <<< "$all")
```

Answer (score 1):

As @choroba said `t1` is created in different subshell and can't be exported back.
You cat test it like this:

```
t1=test
x1=`(time t1=$(echo ok); echo $t1) 2>&1`
echo $t1
echo $x1
```

The output will be:

```
$ echo $t1
test

$ echo $x1
real 0m0,001s user 0m0,001s sys 0m0,001s ok
```

But this litle hack may help

```
fun () { t1=$(mvn test -Drat.skip); }
x1=$((time fun) 2>&1 | grep real)
```